# Can't build idoubs against armv7s

Tags: static-libraries, voip, xcode4.5, iphone-5, armv7

I am using idoubs open source in one of my projects for VoIP functionality. Things are working fine in armv6 and armv7 architecture. Now i am updating my project to support iphone 5. I could not compile the project in armv7s architecture (I dropped armv6 architecture.Tried to compile in armv7 and armv7s architecture). I am getting following error.

**ld: library not found for -lsrtp**

**collect2: ld returned 1 exit status**

Please share your suggestion to solve this issue.

**Note:**

libsrtp.a is available for all the architectures(armv6,armv7 and i386) other than armv7s architecture. So i am not sure that whether the idoubs source code  had been updated really

I am using latest revision r221 and xcode 4.5.

Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 4):

It happened the same to me and I've finally solved it.

When I compile Building for `GPL` version, it was working properly but when I was building non-GPL version was giving 17 errors. First I followed the following steps:

```
In /mydoubs/iPhone/idoubs/branches/2.0/ios-idoubs/idoubs.xcodeproj 
 Right click on idoubs target => Get Info => Build tab => Other Linker Flags then:
        remove -lx264
        replace 
            -lswscale to -lswscale-lgpl
            -lavcore to -lavcore-lgpl
            -lavutil to -lavutil-lgpl
            -lavcodec to -lavcodec-lgpl 


 Right click on ios-ngn-stack target => Get Info => Build tab => Other C Flags then:
            replace -DHAVE_H264=1 with -DHAVE_H264=0
```

Then the trickis to build the libraries in the following order, in the same project don´t forget (`idoubs.xcodeproj`):

1. Doubango(ios-ngn-stack) (be carefull this is different from other Dobango)
2. ios-ngn-stack
3. Doubango (idoubs project)
4. Ngn
5. iDoubs

It is working in this way for armv7

Comment: This is not the place to tell me that. I make a mistake, but why you have to write to me here?

Comment: Hello @Aitul, I followed the same steps. But I am getting the error ld: library not found for -lsrtp
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Answer (score 0):

in "Build Settings" in option:"Valid Architectures" leave only armv7 and user-defined(it's in footer "Build Settings") include in "Doubango liBS" armv7s and choose libs from directory "..youre private path../mydoubs/doubango/branches/2.0/doubango/thirdparties/iphone/lib"!
It's help me!